# How to save post values in db of type xhr with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose as my back-end and I am sending an xhr request (post) to my server in which the field values are sent like in the screen-shot below

[image: Screenshot of request]

This is my server code. When I try to console my values it shows empty even when I send the values. Can anyone please help me?

```
exports.addTest = function (req, res) { 
    var params = req.params;
    var body = req.body;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params, null, 4));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
    var blogsModel = new blogs(params); 
    blogsModel.save(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        res.json(results);
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you show us your blogs schema?

Comment: Are you sending some json objects?
I cannot see properly in image

Comment: Your request is using `multipart/form-data`, for which you can't use `body-parser` but need a module like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).